# Adding together multiple Sum Filter or Sumifs with multiple conditions across multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

So I have a budgeting spread sheet. I have an overview page that I need to link to a "Checkings" sheet and a "CC-Chase" sheet.

To calculate the amount spent on a specific category that month I currently use:
`=sum(filter(Checkings!$B:$B,Checkings!$C:$C=("Grocery"),Checkings!$A:$A>=("1/1/21")+0,Checkings!$A:$A<=("1/31/21")+0))`

I want to add in the same data from my credit card statments so I tried:
`=sum(filter(Checkings!$B:$B,Checkings!$C:$C=("Grocery"),Checkings!$A:$A>=("1/1/21")+0,Checkings!$A:$A<=("1/31/21")+0))+(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery", 'CC-Chase'!$B:$B>=("1/1/21")+0,'CC-Chase'!$B:$B<=("1/31/21")+0)))`

I have also tried:
`=sum(filter(Checkings!$B:$B,Checkings!$C:$C=("Grocery"),Checkings!$A:$A>=("1/1/21")+0,Checkings!$A:$A<=("1/31/21")+0))+sum(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery", 'CC-Chase'!$B:$B>=("1/1/21")+0,'CC-Chase'!$B:$B<=("1/31/21")+0)))`

But these gives me an error. I've tried a few other combinations of this but always get an error.

ACCESS FIXED - Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QhEB-Z0O-ZEEK1zGlJrhdZnfFrEg8PIIV6bS_MI08w/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have another way I could do this?

[image: Overview Tab where I'm trying to use the formula to pull from the other two and sum them]

[image: Checkings Tab to pull data from]

[image: CC-Chase Tab to also pull data from]

Comment: Welcome. What result were you expecting? The most obvious difference between the two formula is that you `sum` the filter for "Checkings" but you don't `sum` the filter for "CC-Chase".

Comment: I want to pull the sum of anything with the category "Grocery" from both "Checking" and "CC-Chase" if the date is in January. I've tried this as well:

'=sum(filter(Checkings!$B:$B,Checkings!$C:$C=("Grocery"),Checkings!$A:$A>=("1/1/21")+0,Checkings!$A:$A<=("1/31/21")+0))+sum(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery", 'CC-Chase'!$B:$B>=("1/1/21")+0,'CC-Chase'!$B:$B<=("1/31/21")+0)))'

but even with the additional sum I still get an error. I'll upload some screenshots.

Comment: Understand that writing or helping to solve formulas when we don't have access to your sheet or data is challenging. It either all has to be done in our heads without testing, or we'd have to manually enter all of your data ourselves to test (which is unrealistic). The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it). That said, scanning it, try simply removing the final closing parenthesis from your third formula shown in your post.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! Sorry first time posting something on here. I'll share a copy of the sheet and add it to the main post too. Also I did try to remove the parenthesis but still same error shows up.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QhEB-Z0O-ZEEK1zGlJrhdZnfFrEg8PIIV6bS_MI08w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You've set the spreadsheet so that "access" must be applied for. If you want the maximum number of volunteers to look at your issue, please allow access to anyone with the url.

Comment: Ok I think I fixed the link so that anyone with the link can edit it now. I thought I was that way to began and didn't realize it wasn't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **just a spelling mistake** in your formula

This part: `+sum(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery",`
**should be**: `+sum(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery"),`

Actually **you do NOT need the parenthesis around the text values**.
You can replace `("Grocery")` with `"Grocery"`

---

**EDIT** *(after having a look at your sheet)*

**Pro Tip**

You can further simplify your formula using the [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) function instead of the ones you now use,
turning this formula

```
=SUM(FILTER('CC-Chase'!$F:$F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D=("Grocery"),'CC-Chase'!$B:$B>=("1/1/21")+0,'CC-Chase'!$B:$B<=("1/31/21")+0))
```

**to this formula**

```
=SUMIFS('CC-Chase'!F:F,'CC-Chase'!$D:$D,"=Grocery",'CC-Chase'!$B:$B,">=1/1/21",'CC-Chase'!$B:$B,"<=1/31/21")
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much! I've been trying for so long to get this to work and never saw that. Also thank you for the SUMIF solution as well! I had tried to do it with the SUMIFS previously but wasn't able to get it to work but with your solution I now see why for that as well.

Comment: Glad I could help.